# Array push replace old data by new one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a cart system in my app with `vuejs` I have a list of products, I loop those by `v-for` directive this fine, but the problem is when I want to add a product in a cart it added and I checked there `id` have or not if `id` exist then I update the `quantity` else push, but the main problem is that when I want to push new product in my cart the new show only and the old one is hidden from the array,

you can see my `gif` [image here](https://i.imgur.com/V0SnIXt.gifv) it shows only the last one which means that whatever product I want to add only shows that one, other not, I searched a lot and found many solutions but nothing works for me, my bad luck.

#### Shop.vue

here I loop my products and pass the `product` prop in my **ProductCard.vue**

```html
<div class="product-cards row">
  <ProductCard
     v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"

    :product="product"
    class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4"
  />
</div>
```

In my

#### ProductCard.vue

```html
<template>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="product__btn add_to_cart_btn"
   
    @click.prevent="addToCart(product)"

    :disabled="addCartLoading"
  >
    Add to cart
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from "../app";

export default {
    name: "ProductCard",

    props: {
        product: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            addCartLoading: false,
            shoppingCart: [],
            quantity: 1
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addToCart(product) {
            let found = this.shoppingCart.find(cart => cart.id === product.id)

            if (found !== undefined && found !== null) {

                found.qty = ++this.quantity

            } else {
                this.shoppingCart.push({
                    id: product.id,
                    name: product.name,
                    qty: 1,
                    price: product.price,
                    options: {
                        old_price: product.old_price,
                        image: product.image,
                    }
                })
            }
           
            EventBus.$emit('cartContents', this.shoppingCart)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

when I console.log(this.shoppingCart) it looks like this, if add new then it should looks like

```html
[
 0:
  id: 11,
  image: url,
  .......,

 1:
  id: 12,
  image: url,
  ....
]
```

but not, when I add new it shows like below the image

[image: console image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem exists because you are having one shopping cart with each `ProductCard` component.

In pseudocode what you are doing is:

```
1. render each ProductCard
2. click on the "add cart" button
3. add the product to the cart of this specific `ProductCard` component
4. use the event bus to emit this new shopping cart (therefore replacing the old one)
```

You should reconsider your code to only emit the product that was added. Your application only has one shopping cart. It doesn't have `n` shopping carts, therefore you only need one instance of the shopping cart.

A solution to your problem (please, feel free to change it to your needs) could be something like this:

### ProductCard

```js
<template>...</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...,
  methods: {
    addToCart(product) {
            EventBus.$emit('cartContents', product)
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then we would handle this emit event by following this simple pseudo-code:

```
1. receive event
2. check if this product is already in the cart
3. if it is in cart increment its quantity
4. if it's not in the cart insert a new product in the cart with quantity 1
```

Translating to Javascript something like this:

```js
const products = [];

// 1. receive event
const onProductAdded = (product) => {
  // 2. check if this product is already in cart
  const product = products.find(p => p.id === product.id);

  // 4. if its not in cart insert new product in cart with quantity 1
  if (!product) {
    //  the same as doing `products.unshift({ id: product.id, quantity: 1, "and so on to all other properties" })`
    products = [{...product, quantity: 1}, ...products];
    
    return;
  }

  // 3. if it is in cart increment its quantity
  const selectedProductIndex = products.findIndex(p => p.id === product.id);
  products[selectedProductIndex] = {...products[selectedProductIndex], quantity: products[selectedProductIndex].quantity + 1};
}
```

Comment: yes that was the problem thanks a lot, now it's working fine.